# Yii2 Gridview table showing Data

Tags: gridview, yii2, widget

my problem is next. I use the Yii2 gridview table and the user id I recorded in the session. And if I log in with the user who has for example ID 2, I want to display the data in the table only for the user with ID 2. Thanks for the answers in advance.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

    'company_name',
    'person_name',
    'company_address',
    'company_email:email',
    'meeting_date',
    'user_id',//external key
    'tel_fix',
    'tel_mob',

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{view} {update}'],
  ],
  'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
]); ?>
```

Here is my actionIndex from PartnersController.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PartnersSearch();

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

And where can I do that?

Thank's a lot!
But in your code, I made just one change and now it works great!

Instead of :

```
$query->andFilterWhere ( [
        'user_partner_id' => $this->user_partner_id,
      ] );
```

I wrote :

```
$query->andFilterWhere ( [
        'user_partner_id' => $_SESSION['sess_id_user'],
      ] );
```

Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: add the action from the controller that is used with this gridview and your `searchModel` for the `Company`

Comment: or whichever model it is

Comment: By Class PartnersSearch and Method Search, I wrote : $query = Partners::find()->where('user_partner_id',$_SESSION['sess_id_user']); But it does not work.

Comment: yeah but you need to addd the action code here so that the exact soultion is provided , just add the code for the `controller/action` and the `search()` function from the `PartnerSearch` model, it is easier and quick to add few lines rather than writing on assumptions.

Comment: Please update your question and add code of your controller action.

Comment: you should add the details in your question rather than the comments, but anyway i posted an answer below, see if it helps out and if you run into errors you need to **first add the relative code inyour question and then ask for the fix**.

Comment: isnt there a field named `user_partner_id` in the `Partner` model and added as `safe` inside the `PartnerSearch` model rules , if yes then how come it is not working, **you should not hardcode it inside the model like this** it will show only the records that are associated to the admins whereas it should show everything to the admins of the site, this is wrong. Please add your complete search model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UserModel`, just replace your query in `SearchModel` :

```
     $query->andFilterWhere ([
                'user_partner_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->sess_id_user,
            ]);
```

Or if your `sess_id_user` is primary key in `UserModel`:

```
     $query->andFilterWhere ([
                'user_partner_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list only the records for the user that is logged in you need to do the following

In your `controller/action` add the following before you call the `search()` function from the model, i am assuming the name of the action is `actionIndex()` and the view name is `index` you can change them to your relative names.

You should not hardcode the `user_partner_id` in the query inside the `search()` function

```
 //THIS IS WRONG
 $query = Partners::find()->where('user_partner_id',$_SESSION['sess_id_user']);
```

but instead, you should pass it via params to the `search()` method as your PartnersSearch will be used by admins too which need to have all records accessible.

Change you `controller/action`

```
public function actionIndex(){
   $searchModel = new \common\models\PartnersSearch();
   $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
   $params['PartnersSearch']['user_partner_id'] = Yii::$app->user->id;
   $dataProvider = $model->search ( $params );
   $this->render('index',['searchModel']);
}
```

and make sure you have the `andFilterWhere` condition added for the `user_partner_id` in the `search()` function of the `CompanySearch` model or add one before you return the `$dataProvider` in the `search()` method.

```
  public function search( $params ) {
        $query = PartnersSearch::find ();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ( [
            'query' => $query ,
                ] );

        $this->load ( $params );

        if ( !$this->validate () ) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        //your rest of code
        .................

        /*THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE ADDED*/
        $query->andFilterWhere ( [
            'user_partner_id' => $this->user_partner_id,
        ] );
         /*THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE ADDED*/

         return $dataProvider;
}
```

## `EDIT`

Make sure your field `user_partner_id` from the `Partner` model is added to the `safe` rules inside the `PartnerSearch` Model otherwise it wont load the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition directly in controller action after creating `$dataProvider`:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new PartnersSearch();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataprovider->query->andWhere(['user_partner_id' => $_SESSION['sess_id_user']]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

---

Note that using `andFilterWhere()` in such cases may be dangerous - condition will be skipped if `$_SESSION['sess_id_user']` is empty. So if user is a guest, it may see all the records if you not disallow guest access for this action.

Comment: hmm, it will also prevent the text population inside the gridview filter input as in my answer, `+1`.